# How to use one object to cut a hole into another one

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, knife-tool

My issue is that I have 2 objects in edit mode, I want to use the second object to cut the first one to make a hole.

I hope the image can make what I want a little clear because I don't find the right words to explain that.

Thank you~

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use Knife Project tool.

Comment: I can't use Knife Project, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Knife Project* tool.

> **Blender Manual**
>   To use *Knife Project*, first while in *Object Mode*, select the “cutting object” then select the “object to be cut”. Now, enter *Edit Mode* and press *Knife Project* (found in the *Mesh > Knife Project*).

When you're done, just delete the "cutting object" and also any unwanted faces from the cut object.

[image]

Comment: I can't use knife Profect, I get a message said "No other selected object found to use for projection"
I think because bot of the is inside the edit mode

Comment: Sure. In that case, just select the polygon and separate it into another object. *Mesh > Separate > Selection*.

Comment: it's work like a magic~
Thank you a lot, you too  Lukasz-40sth
Respect